# How do i get CentOS6 to send outgoing email to any email address?

Tags: linux, centos, email, postfix

I want to set up an email server to send email notifications only. I have postfix isntalled already. I have an email address admin@something.com with outgoing server abc.def.com using smtp port 465. How do i get this to work? I am very new at this and I can't find my answer at other sites. I really need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a hard time believing you couldn't find one of the **thousands** of postfix howtos out there. Did you try anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is at the following URL

http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#lists

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
# Relay control (Postfix 2.10 and later): local clients and
# authenticated clients may specify any destination domain.
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
...
```

Follow the links and you'll realise how easy it is to set it up yourself